# ios + button on side menu not working

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

I am able to implement side menu functionality using below code:

```
-(IBAction)menu:(id)sender
{
    if (!_menuView) {
        _menuView=[[MenuWidget alloc]init];
        _menuView.view.frame=CGRectMake(-160,0,160,440);
        [self.view addSubview:_menuView.view];
        [self.view sendSubviewToBack:_menuView.view];

        _menuView.view.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    }



    if(self.widgetFlag==0){
        //  menuView.view.frame=CGRectMake(-160,20,160,548);
        self.view.frame=CGRectMake(0, 20, 320, 548);
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                         animations:^{
                             self.view.frame=CGRectMake(160, 20, 320, 548);
                             // menuView.view.frame=CGRectMake(0,20,160,548);
                         }];

        self.widgetFlag=1;
    }
    else{
        self.view.frame=CGRectMake(160, 20, 320, 548);
        // menuView.view.frame=CGRectMake(0,20,160,548);
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                         animations:^{
                             self.view.frame=CGRectMake(0, 20, 320, 548);
                             // menuView.view.frame=CGRectMake(-160,20,160,548);
                         }];
        self.widgetFlag=0;
    }
}
```

It is working properly, but only problem is:

> Button added on _menuView.view is not responding to associated action.

Please suggest if I am missing anything.

Comment: Are you using interface builder to add the button or doing it programmatically?

Comment: Add the code you are using to create this button and assign it the action

Comment: I have added button directly in IB, and binded an action to the same.